# Shnaim Asar Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred twelve?

### ?שנים עשר ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 312.

Don't dwell on lazy gematria; it's bad to get caught up in something so dry.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous three hundred eleven entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Comment: It's more _embarrassing_ to get caught up in something so dry.

Comment: @DoubleAA Still worse if you get arrested and taken captive for doing so.

Comment: @Fred "caught up," even

Comment: @IsaacMoses Ah, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Azara of the third Bais Hamikdash which will hopefully be built soon will be 312 x 317 Ammos.

> [כל העזרה החיצונה אורך שי"ז על רוחב שי"ב. מן המזרח למערב שי"ז, ממנה עד
>   הפנימית מאה אמה, כותל הפנימית שש, ותוכה מאה, ההיכל מאה אמה, וי"א אמה
>   לאחורי בית הכפורת. מן הצפון לדרום שי"ב, ממנה עד הפנימית מאה אמה, כותל
>   הפנימית לצפון שש, ותוכה מאה, וכתלה לדרום שש, ממנו ולכותל מאה
>   אמה:](http://www.hebrew.grimoar.cz/luzzato/miskani_elijon.htm)
>
> [בבית המקדש השלישי, הר הבית יתרחב לגודל של 3000/3000 אמה, ובתוכו בית
>   המקדש ששטחו הכולל יהיה 317/312 אמה שזה 10% משטח הר הבית.](http://www.chabad.info/#!g=1&url=article&id=70438)